# get aws-sdk parameters without session

Tags: angular, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm wondering if this is even possible - I need to get parameters from the AWS store to use certain values in each environment without redeploying the Angular app each time to pick up the change in appSettings.json

I have the following code which works well until the SessionToken expires.  This is a public site so will not have an authed user.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SSMClient, GetParameterCommand, GetParameterCommandInput } from '@aws-sdk/client-ssm';
import { fromTemporaryCredentials } from '@aws-sdk/credential-providers';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SsmService {

  constructor() {}

  creds = {
    accessKeyId: 'accessKeyId',
    secretAccessKey: 'secretAccessKey',
    sessionToken: 'sessionToken'
  }

  tempCreds = fromTemporaryCredentials({
    masterCredentials: this.creds,
    params: {
      RoleArn: 'arn:RoleArn',
      RoleSessionName: 'RoleSessionName',
      DurationSeconds: 3600
    },
    clientConfig: {
      region: 'eu-west-2'
    }
  });

  client: SSMClient = new SSMSClient(
  {
    region: 'eu-west-2',
    credentials: this.tempCreds
  });

  async getParameterValue(name: string): Promise<string> {
    const input: GetParameterCommandInput = {
      Name: name
    }

    const command = new GetParameterCommand(input);

    return await this.client.send(command).Parameter?.Value ?? '';
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get parameters without the SessionToken?

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to call AWS API without valid session token.

> I have the following code which works well until the SessionToken expires.

Why not just get a new session token from STS before the old token expires?

One way to fetch configuration data without credentials and authentication is to load them from local config file (see, for example https://jooooel.com/angular-config-from-an-external-source/). Surely this cannot be used to load credentials or other confidential data. The idea is to store unconfidential config and settings data in a json file and load it dynamically before app launch. Every environment can have a different config file.